# container cacheCanvas & context drawing issue

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs

1) I'm caching a container filled with objects and then getting the canvas with .cacheCanvas in easel. I use this canvas as a bitmap image for my background (for performance reasons).

2) When I want to make minor changes to the image, rather than re-caching the large container, I get the context('2d') of the cachedCanvas(that I store in an easel Bitmap() ) and I draw onto the cachedCanvas.

The issue i'm having is when I draw onto the context of a cachedCanvas, it seems like the canvas is shared with the container and the bitmap, so when I do step 2) all of the imageDraws that I do are also done to the container. After repeating step 1) I want just the container and it's objects. (Not all of the context.draws that I did in step 2) )

**TLDR: Is there a proper way to draw on a cachedCanvas, but also have the ability to revert to the original cachedCanvas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by using uncache();